# Using Linq to get summaries and count

Tags: linq, count, execution, deferred

I have a SQL Server database with an Events table that stores around a million events, each with a dateStart, dateEnd, title, rating and other bits.

I need to display a list of years, where each year displays the 5 highest rated events and the total count of events in that year.

So, something like...

> **Top 5 events for 2009** (from 199 events)
>    - Event A
>    - Event B
>    - Event C
>    - Event D
>    - Event E
>
> **Top 5 events for 2010** (from 469 events)
>    - Event F
>    - Event G
>    - Event H
>    - Event I
>    - Event J
>
> .... etc.

Because of the sheer quantity of records, I'd like to avoid a Linq query that will pull everything out of the database, but I don't know if that is possible and my Linq knowledge is not enough to work out how this would work.

What is the most efficient method for retrieving this data structure from the database?

Thanks a lot in advance - been mangling my brain all day trying to work it out.

Comment: What ORM are you using? NHibernate? EF? LINQ to SQL? Something else that has a LINQ provider?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's assume that you only care about the start date. You'd want something like:

```
var query = from eventInfo in db.Events
            group eventInfo by eventInfo.dateStart.Year into g
            select
            {
                Year = g.Key, // Key for the grouping
                Count = g.Count(), // Events for this year
                Top5 = g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rating).Take(5)
            };
```

Frankly I have no idea what kind of SQL that will produce, or if it'll be even vaguely efficient - you should find out the SQL generated, and then look in the SQL profiler to see that the query execution plan is.

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks a lot.  Not sure about performance yet, but it certainly does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an ORM, there are several possibilites, including (but not limited to) Linq-To-Sql, Entity Framework, NHibernate (I'm not sure about LINQ support here), etc.

All of those will translate the LINQ query operators to an sql query that will be executed in the database, and will only return the information you need or requested.